# Swapping variables within a method

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm trying to learn some OOP, so bear with me. I need to use a variable I defined in one function, elsewhere. Here is my example code (I want `INTERCEPT!!` to be logged, but it returns undefined):

```
function Talk() {
    var greeting;
    var pleaseStop; // declare it

    this.A = function () {
        greeting = 'hello';
        console.log(greeting);

        var intercept = function () {
           pleaseStop = 'INTERCEPT!';
        }
    }

    this.B = function () {
        greeting = 'goodbye';
        console.log(pleaseStop); // this returns undefined!
        console.log(greeting);
    }
}

var activateTalk = new Talk();

activateTalk.A();

activateTalk.B();
```

This whole code logs the following:

```
hello
undefined
goodbye
```

I have also tried `intercept.pleaseStop()` but it still returns undefined. Would anyone know of a solution?

**EDIT**:

I've removed the `var` the second time, but it still returns undefined:

http://jsfiddle.net/d654H/2/

Comment: Checkout variable scoping. `pleaseStop` is local to the `intercept` function - the only way you can access that is either declare it further up the scope or `return` `pleasestop` from the `intercept`

Comment: Where are you calling `intercept`?

Comment: [Here, this works](http://jsfiddle.net/d654H/1/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `var` in front of the assignment to `pleaseStop`.

This assigns a new value to the `pleaseStop` declared inside the constructor, which is visible also from inside `B`:

```
var intercept = function () {
     pleaseStop = 'INTERCEPT!';
}
```

This declares a new local variable `pleaseStop`, completely unrelated to the other `pleaseStop`, that is not visible outside `intercept`:

```
var intercept = function () {
     var pleaseStop = 'INTERCEPT!';
}
```

If you do the latter instead of the former, you end up changing the value of another variable than the one you intended.

Comment: A good answer explains _why_, instead of just dictating resolution steps.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Just editing that in. Still doing so.

Comment: @tmyie You define the `intercept` function, but you never call it. http://jsfiddle.net/d654H/3/

Comment: @tmyie: Well, you need to also call `intercept` so that it can change the value. You aren't doing that anywhere.

Comment: @Jon: Okay so you're FGITWing :(

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Yeah. I figure that if someone is going to be the FGITW (as is invariably going to happen in questions like this), I would prefer that someone to be me. If it's good enough for Jon Skeet, it's good enough for me.

Answer (score 2):

```
var pleaseStop = 'INTERCEPT!';
```

You're *declaring* a new, function-local variable here; drop the `var` to *assign* to the existing variable in scope.

Then, you need to actually *call* `intercept`; at the moment you only define it.

It's your choice as to when you call that function; in [this live example](http://jsfiddle.net/Wn2xy/) I simply do so immediately after the definition, for the purposes of exposition.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you never set `pleaseStop`. You have declared `intercept` as a function, but you never called it. Therefore, `pleaseStop` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

**Without `var` keyword.**

```
var pleaseStop  = "A";
function foo(){
    pleaseStop = "B"; // overwriting to "B"
}
foo();
alert(pleaseStop); // shows "B"
```

**With `var` keyword.**

```
var pleaseStop  = "A";
function foo(){
    var pleaseStop  = "B" 
    // This defines a new variable 'pleaseStop'
    //  in the scope of function foo(){}.
}
foo();
alert(pleaseStop); // shows "A"
```

**Variable Scope**
JavaScript has **function-level** scope. In most languages which have **block-level** variable scope, variable are accessible whithin their block surrounded by curly brackets ({and}). But JavaSciprt doesn't terminate scopes at the end of blocks, but terminate them at the end of functions.

I'm sure there are many articles and documents about it. I googled it and found an intresting introductory article.
http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-variable-scope-and-hoisting-explained/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have't called intercept() anywhere and also u did something

```
var pleaseStop = 'INTERCEPT!';
```

which will create new variable instead of initializing global variable

You can do something like this

```
function Talk() {
    var greeting;
    var pleaseStop; // declare it
    this.A = function () {
        greeting = 'hello';
        console.log(greeting);

        var intercept = function () {
             pleaseStop = 'INTERCEPT!';//changed
        }
      intercept(); //..Added
    }

    this.B = function () {
        greeting = 'goodbye';
        console.log(pleaseStop); // this returns undefined!
        console.log(greeting);
    }
}

var activateTalk = new Talk();

activateTalk.A();

activateTalk.B();
```